# Wicked PDF with password protection

Tags: ruby, wicked-pdf

**Can anyone tell me that how to make password on wicked PDF before open?**
Or

Is there any way to make wicked pdf password protective.

Comment: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/546 They are planing to add this feature in wicked pdf

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to figure it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had already gone through that link, but nothing happened.
Yes, it's true that they will be implementing in future but client wants password functionality within 2 or 3 days.

So, therefore Now I'm trying to implement with Prawn gem which is a little difficult because  I'm not familiar with Prawn.
Pdf is too big therefore I am little worried because it can take time may be more than 1 week.

But if anyone will suggest with wicked pdf, will be appreciated.

Thanks